# ASP custom forms authentication is not working because the cookie is lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, iprincipal

I have an ASP .Net 4.5 MVC website where I have customized the forms authentication following [this tutorial](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html). The difference is that I'm authenticating via a backend dll, so I have skipped all the database-stuff in the tutorial and where the tutorial fetches the user from the database I get it from a regular method call. 
I have followed this tutorial before and successfully implemented it in a new MVC website. This time I have implemented it on an existing MVC website, and I cannot get it to work.

When the cookie is added to `Response.Cookies` it only exists until the code returns a View to the user. After that it does no longer exist in `Response.Cookies` and this means that in the Global.asax `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` method, `var authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];` always returns `null`.
I have tried to add other simple cookies and these persist as expected.

This is how I add the forms authentication cookie

```
CustomUser user = service.GetUser(username, password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
                {
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    UserId = user.Id
                };

                var userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializeModel);
                var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.Id, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, userData);
                var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30) };
                Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
            }
```

And if I change this line

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30) };
```

To

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("test", "testing") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30) };
```

Then the "test" cookie will act as expected and I can get it in Global.asax `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`